# How can I move files by creation date into variable folders using C# and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

My mentor at work (I'm on helpdesk but I'm really trying not to be) has assigned me a problem in C#, and while I have researched and experimented, nothing's working the way I'd like it to.

Here is the problem:
"You have code that will sort all files created today from a source folder into a destination folder at the end of 'C:/root/yyyy/MM/dd' where yyyyMMdd corresponds to the creation date of the files created today. However, you also have files that were made prior to today. How can you also sort the older files into folders that follow the same 'C:/root/yyyy/MM/dd' format?"

So in short, the desired end result is to have files that were made on 6/19/23 to be put into C:/root/2023/06/19, and files that were made on 10/2/23 (today) to be put into C:/root/2023/02/10.

This is the starter code I have that sorts today's files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace VPorganizer
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Created variables for root directory and rundate.
            string rootdir = @"C:\Users\memyself\Documents\VPOrgTEST";
            DateTime rundate = DateTime.Now;
            string runyear = rundate.ToString("yyyy");
            string runmonth = rundate.ToString("MM");
            string runday = rundate.ToString("dd");
            
            string subdir = String.Join(@"\", rootdir, runyear, runmonth, runday) + @"\";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(subdir);


            //This returns a file list from the root directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(rootdir);
            FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();
            
            //This looks for files with today's date and compares it to the rundate. If there's a match, it moves the file to the folder corresponding to the last write time.
            foreach (FileInfo file in fi) 
            {
                string destfile = subdir + file.Name;
                if (file.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") == rundate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) 
                {
                    File.Move(file.FullName, destfile);   
                }

            }
```

And this is what I've been trying so far:

````
//Trying to move files with access date = prior to 'now' into their own subfolders. For each file where the last access date does NOT equal the run date, make a subdir+filename
//corresponding to that last access date.

//foreach (FileInfo file in fi)
//{
//  string destfile = subdir + file.Name;
//if (file.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) 
//} This code moved Good to know.txt from rootdir to VPOrgTEST/2023/10/2 and left the other files alone.

//foreach (FileInfo file in fi)
//{
  //  string destfile2 = subdir + file.Name;
    //if (file.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyMMdd") != rundate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
    //{
      //  File.Move (file.FullName, destfile2);
    //}
//} This code moved all of the files in rootdir to VPOrgTEST/2023/10/2. Suspect I'm on the right track, but I need to do something with subdirectory or the rundate.```

I feel like I'm on the right track, but I know next to nothing about C#, and Google's turned up empty so far. I would really appreciate some help.
````

Comment: Instead of looking for files with the LastWriteTimes matching the run date, just loop the files and read the LastWriteTime for each file, then using the LastWriteTime for each file move it to the correct date directory. It seems you don't need to worry about the run date, just the LastWriteTime, and that LastWriteTime will determine the correct directory to move it to.

Answer (score 0):

You are very "hung up" on the way the first program works.  Instead you need a new plan that is generic for all file:

1. look at each file to archive in a loop
2. for each file archive that file

   2.a check if the needed directory exists (if it doesn't create it)

   2.b move the file to the archive

You can use code from the original example to do this but this is a total re-work of the process.  This algorithm does not care about new files and old files -- it solves the problem for all files.

Comment: I think I can see the logic in your answer, but if I’m putting files into folders based on creation date, don’t I have to check for the existence of every possible date on its own line? Can’t I do a “get file creation date, output that as yyyyMMdd, and then parse that out into the destination directory as yyyy/MM/dd” without having to define each date?

Comment: @user22671676 for each file you check for the existence of it's date and create it if it does not exist then copy it to that folder.